# vector to array and array size in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a  struct:

```
struct xyz{
    int x,y,z;
};
```

and I initialize a `struct xyz` type vector:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
            {
                v.x=i;
                v.y=j;
                v.z=k;
                vect.push_back(v);
            }
        }
    }
```

then I want to transform that vector to array because array is 2 time faster than vector to manipulate, so I do

```
 xyz arr[vect.size()];
 std::copy(vect.begin(), vect.end(), arr);
```

when I run this program it shows me segmentation fault which I think is because `vect.size()` is too large.
So I am wondering is there any way to convert that large size vector to array without that problem.
I appreciate for any help

Comment: You need to use the heap (`new`) since the size of the vector is not known until runtime.

Comment: Where do you get *because array is 2 time faster than vector to manipulate*?  A vector, used properly, should be nearly identical to an array in terms of speed.

Comment: 1) VLAs (`xyz arr[vect.size()];`) are non-standard C++ 2) You think? Did you try _anything_ to resolve the issue by yourself (e.g. debugger)? 3) _I want to transform that vector to array because array is 2 time faster than vector to manipulate_ Where did you read this nonsense?

Comment: Either you know how the number of`xyz` instances at compile time or you do not. Use `std::array` if you do or use `std::vector` if you don't. There is nothing to gain from mixing these containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My overly pedantic comment got too big, so instead I'll try to make this a somewhat roundabout answer. The short answer is probably just to stick with `vector` but make sure to use `reserve`; oh, and benchmark.

You didn't say what compiler or C++ version you're using, so I'll just go with my current [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org) default of gcc 4.9.2, C++14. I'm also assuming that you really want this as a 1-dimension array, rather than the more natural (for your example) 3.

If you know `N` at compile time, you could do something like this (assuming I got the array offset calculation correct):

```
#include <array>
...
std::array<xyz, N*N*N> xyzs;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
      xyzs[i*N*N+j*N+k] = {i, j, k};
    }
  }
}
```

The biggest downsides, IMO:

- error-prone offset calculation
- depending on `N`, where the code is run, etc, this can blow the stack

On the compilers I tried this on, the optimizers seem to understand that we're moving through the array in contiguous order, and the generated machine code is more sensible, but it could also be written like so, if you prefer:

```
#include <array>
...
std::array<xyz, N*N*N> xyzs;
auto p = xyzs.data();
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
      (*p++) = {i, j, k};
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, if you actually know `N` at compile time, and it won't blow the stack, you might consider a 3-dimensional array `xyz xyzs[N][N][N];` since this might be more natural for the way these things are being ultimately being used.

As pointed out in comments, variable length arrays aren't legal C++, but they are legal in C99; if you don't know `N` at compile time you should be allocating off the heap.

A `vector` and an array will wind up being identical in terms memory layout; they differ in that `vector` allocates memory from the heap, and the array (as you are writing it) would be on the stack. The only recommendation I'd make is to call `reserve` before entering your loop:

```
vect.reserve(N*N*N);
```

This means you'll only be doing a single memory allocation up front, rather than grow-and-copy mechanism that you'll get from a default constructed `vector`.

Assuming `xyz` is as simple as you declare here, you could also do something like the second example above:

```
std::vector<xyz> xyzs{N*N*N};
auto p = xyzs.data();
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
      (*p++) = {i, j, k};
    }
  }
}
```

You lose the safety of `push_back`, and it is less efficient if `xyz` default constructor needs to do anything (like if `xyz` members were changed to have default values).

Having said all that, you really should benchmark. But then, you should probably be benchmarking the code that ultimately uses this array, rather than the code to construct it; I'd have other concerns if construction was dominating usage.